# Are there good references for moving from Perl to Powershell?

Tags: perl, powershell

I hate to say it, but powershell is really annoying me.  I just cannot seem to get my mind around it. I have an O'Reilly book on the topic, and I can see how to do some extremely powerful stuff -- it's the easy stuff I can't seem to get right.

### Case in point: Iterate across a list of filenames.

#### In CMD:

```
for /F %x in ('dir EXPRESSION') do @(
   arbitrary-action %x
)
```

#### In Perl:

```
@foo=glob("*");
foreach (@foo)
{
   arbitrary-command $_ ;
}
```

#### In Powershell:

```
I'm dumbfounded.  I can't seem to get it right.
```

But I am not sending this post so somebody can tell me the answer.  I don't want the answer to this simple question.  I want to know how to figure it out, and Google/Bing searches are just not cutting it.  The get-help functionality is powershell is nice, but it's still not enough.

I've been programming for 20 years.
I've learned BASIC, Fortran, C, Pascal, Perl, C++, C#, BASH and CMD scripting...And never have I had the trouble I'm having with Powershell.

Are there no references "out there" for migrating from Perl to Powershell?  It seems like such a straightforward thing to publish, but I have yet to find one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

Okay, so maybe this wasn't the best example to post.

I think I was thrown off by the fact that when I tried gci interactively, I got a directory listing, where what I wanted was an array of strings.

```
I took a leap of faith and tried:

    foreach ($foo in gci "*") {
        echo $foo;
    }
```

And yeah, it worked. And yes, I can continue to do searches to piece my way through. I guess I was just hoping to find a guide that makes use of the similarity to languages I already know. I know that Microsoft published a VBScript-to-Powershell guide, so I was hoping for a Perl equivalent.

Thanks again

Comment: What about the standard Google approach where you learn to do one thing at a time? For instance I found the solution to this in a single query. I'd expect you having a book and all might clarify the solutions you find on Google.

Comment: BTW, the terms of the query were powershell+iterate+over+a+list+of+filenames

Comment: It is not easy to find a Perl to Powershell guide on the major search engines.  There is nothing wrong with answering questions that are easily found on Google.  By asking them and getting them answered here they may become even easier to find in the future.

Comment: Even with C as a point of reference you still have to slog through those first 3 dry chapters of the Camel book trying every sample/function before Perl gets dangerous/effective/useful enough to be a self-rewarding exercise for a newbie. The same goes for PowerShell - even with .Net as a point of reference.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen such a guide.  I've seen something to help people going from VBScript to PowerShell.

[Bruce Payette](http://www.manning.com/payette/)'s PowerShell in Action does have a few pages on PowerShell vs X scripting language, but that won't cut it for a conversion guide.

Now, there was a site out there that had all kinds of constructs in multiple languages, thus providing a task, and then going about solving it in all kinds of languages based on answers from the community...  Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: There's Rosetta Code at http://rosettacode.org/ but there are few powershell examples there.  There is another site, but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: Ah, it's PLEAC - http://pleac.sourceforge.net/ but no powershell examples at all.

Comment: There may be some examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rosetta-stone but they may be few, and far between.

Comment: daotoad: Trying to change that sad fact about Rosetta Code :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any good Perl to Powershell comparisons but I can answer your secondary question.

```
$files = get-childitem "c:\test\" -filter *.dll
foreach ($file in $files) { $file.Name }
```

There are two different ways you can express a [`foreach`](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_loops.htm) loop in Powershell.

You can pipe an array of objects into `foreach` and `$_` becomes the current object on each iteration.

```
0,1,2,3 | foreach { $_ }
```

Alternatively, you can pass a variable to iterate over.

```
foreach ($num in 0,1,2,3) { $num }
```

Output in both cases.

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: anyone want to explain the -1?

Comment: Wasn't me, but I figure it's due the OP saying "I don't want the answer to this simple question. I want to know how to figure it out."

Comment: That's true, kind of a bummer that my answer is the same as everyone elses (but does answer the simple question) and someone downvoted... you have a valid point though, I should have read the question more thuroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Like he said himself, he realized the potential to get some very powerful things using powershell...I recently started using it myself and the ease with which things can be done is astounding...just a few lines is all it takes to accomplish things that in python woulda taken me some extra workarounds etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious do you have the powershell cookbook? I thought since I had programming experience that it would be the best way to quickly learn powershell. This turned out to be a poor assumption. Even though the book was really good, I was struggling because I needed a book that was structured more for learning than reference.

The two best free online ebooks I found are:

https://blogs.technet.com/chitpro-de/archive/2007/05/10/english-version-of-windows-powershell-course-book-available-for-download.aspx

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/

I'm still looking for a good print book.

Answer (score 0):

Funny... I had the same issues when I started with PowerShell, but after using PowerShell now for a couple of months, I have dumped Perl like ugly Sally after the Prom. There are several great ways of using foreach to loop through an list of objects. Let's look at the following example where I have a number of services that I want to make sure are running on my Windows Server (the processes all have Equal in the name). I can do this with a one liner command as follows:

```
Get-Service | where-object {$_.displayname -like "Equal*"} | foreach {
  if($_.Status -eq "Stopped") {
    Write-Host "`nRestarting..."
    write-host $_.DisplayName 
    Start-Service $_.name
  } 
}
```

The first part of the command is the get-service command - filtering the services looking for services with the display name with Equal in them. The next part of the one liner really shows the beauty of PowerShell. The get-service command returns a list of objects, which can then be acted upon by piping them into a foreach loop. Note I did not have to declare any variables or an array to hold the objects. The objects are stored in the default $_ variable from which I can pull out object properties like name and status. Foreach returned object (service) I check its status to see if it's status is stopped and if it is it is restarted with the Start-Service command. I could do this a similar action with Perl, but I would have to screen scrape  and place the values into an array, then foreach over the array in a similar manner as I did above. The screen scrapping would involve grep with regexp which adds lines of code. Because PowerShell commands produce objects with properties, I can quickly drill down to the properties I am looking for without the screen scraping hassles.

Answer (score 0):

I think finding a Perl to PowerShell guide is going to be difficult.  It is actually more accurate to compare PowerShell to BASh and the C Shell than Perl.  I think what makes learning PowerShell difficult from most of the available books is that they are aimed at system admins, not programmers.  I recommend the "PowerShell in Action" for the best coverage of PowerShell as a general purpose programming language.

The other thing you need to do is immediately embrace the core principal of PowerShell -- you are dealing with objects, not text.  With BASh and the other Unix shells, it's all about text manipulation and while Perl can do objects, its roots are still very much in the Unix shell and command line utilities (grep, sed, awk, etc.).

Larry Wall stole a lot of great ideas from other languages when he created Perl.  PowerShell has done the same, using the POSIX shell as its starting point.  You can see a lot of Perl in PowerShell, as well as other languages.  I think the best way to learn PowerShell is by having a PowerShell window in front of you while reading "PowerShell in Action" which will help you get into the PowerShell way of thinking about how it does objects.  It is easy to interactively enter code snippets in a PowerShell window and examine the properties and methods available within the objects returned by the commands.

BTW -- if you are use to using BASh with the *default* command line editing features, put the following command in your PowerShell $PROFILE

`Set-PSReadlineOption -editmode Emacs`

Do this and you'll feel right at home.  Now that I can run PowerShell on Linux and the Mac, I'm not sure what I will ever need BASh for again.