# Powershell Host File edit

Tags: perl, powershell, host

Guys i'm having some issues converting my Perl script to powershell, I need some help. In the host file of our machines, we have all of the URL's to our test environments blocked. In my PERL script, based on which environment is selected, it will comment out the line of the environment selected to allow access and block others so the testers can't mistakenly do things in the wrong environment.

I need help converting to powershell

Below is what I have in PERL:

```
sub editHosts {
print "Editing hosts file...\n";
my $file = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\etc\\hosts';
my $data = readFile($file);
my @lines = split /\n/, $data;
my $row = '1';
open (FILE, ">$file") or die "Cannot open $file\n";
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ m/$web/) { 
        print FILE '#'."$line\n"; }
    else {
        if ($row > '21') {
            $line =~ s/^\#*127\.0\.0\.1/127\.0\.0\.1/;
            $line =~ s/[#;].*$//s; }
        print FILE "$line\n"; }
    $row++;
}
close(FILE);
}
```

Here is what i've tried in Powershell:

```
foreach ($line in get-content "C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts") {
if ($line -contains $web) {
$line + "#"
}
```

I've tried variation including set-content with what used to be in the host file, etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Grant

Comment: I don't know Perl so I'm probably reading this wrong... Doesn't `m/$web/` = line starts with "web"? A host file starts with `         1.1.1.1     somedomain` so that would never work. Please provide a sample hosts file before and after the desired changes.

Comment: Okay :) What does the rest in the else part do? :)

Answer (score 2):

-contains is a "set" operator, not a substring operator.  Try .Contains() or -like.

Answer (score 2):

This will comment out lines matching the variable `$word`, while removing `#` from non-matches (except the header):

```
function Edit-Hosts ([string]$Web, $File = "C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts") {
    #If file exists and $web is not empty/whitespace
    if((Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) -and $web.Trim()) {
        $row = 1

        (Get-Content -Path $file) | ForEach-Object {
            if($_ -like "*$web*") {
                #Matched PROD, comment out line
                "#$($_)"
            } else { 
                #No match. If past header = remove comment
                if($row -gt 21) { $_ -replace '^#' } else { $_ }
            }
            $row++
        } | Set-Content -Path $file

    } else {
        Write-Error -Category InvalidArgument -Message "'$file' doesn't exist or Web-parameter is empty"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Edit-Hosts -Web "PROD"
```

Comment: This works exactly as a desire... However, it does not remove the comment from the old line.. Anyway to do that part as well??

Comment: See updated answer. Next time you should include a sample (before and after) as it's unclear what you want for those who doesn't know perl.

Comment: I apologize, I will keep that in mind for the future. But now it is no longer working...

Comment: Nevermind didn't see you wrapped it in a function!

Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar answer to Frode F.'s answer, but I'm not yet able to comment to add my 2c worth, so have to provide an alternative answer instead.

It looks like one of the gotchas moving from perl to PowerShell, in this example, is that when we get the content of the file using `Get-Content` it is an "offline" copy, i.e. any edits are not made directly to the file itself. One approach is to compile the new content to the *whole* file and then write that back to disk.

I suppose that the `print FILE "some text\n";` construct in perl might be similar to `"some text" | Out-File $filename -Encoding ascii -Append` in PowerShell, albeit you would use the latter either (1) to write line-by-line to a new/empty file or (2) accept that you are appending to existing content.

Two other things about editing the hosts file:

- Be sure to make sure that your hosts file is ASCII encoded; I have caused a major outage for a key enterprise application (50k+ users) in learning that...
- You may need to remember to run your PowerShell / PowerShell ISE by right-clicking and choosing **Run as Administrator** else you might not be able to modify the file.

Anyway, here's a version of the previous answer using `Out-File`:

```
$FileName = "C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
$web = "PROD"

# Get "offline" copy of file contents
$FileContent = Get-Content $FileName

# The following creates an empty file and returns a file
# object (type [System.IO.FileInfo])

$EmptyFile = New-Item -Path $FileName -ItemType File -Force

foreach($Line in $FileContent) {
  if($Line -match "$web") {
    "# $Line" | Out-File $EmptyFile -Append -Encoding ascii
  } else {
    "$Line" | Out-File $EmptyFile -Append -Encoding ascii
  }
}
```

### Edit

1. The `($Line -match "$web")` takes whatever is in the **$web** variable and treats it as a regular expression. In my example I was assuming that you were just wanting to match a simple text string, but you might well be trying to match an IP address, etc. You have a couple of options:

   - Use `($Line -like "*$web*")` instead.
   - Convert what is in $web to be an *escaped* regex, i.e. one that will match literally. Do this with `($Line -match [Regex]::Escape($web))`.
2. You also wanted to strip off comments from any line past row 21 of the hosts file, should that line *not* match **$web**. In perl you have used the **s** substitution operator; the PowerShell equivalent is `-replace`.

So... here is an updated version of that `foreach` loop:

```
$LineCount = 1

foreach($Line in $FileContent) {
  if($Line -match [Regex]::Escape($web) {
    # ADD comment to any matched line
    $Line = "#" + $Line
  } elseif($LineCount -gt 21) {
    # Uncomment the other lines
    $Line = $Line -replace '^[# ]+',''
  }

  # Remove 'stacked up' comment characters, if any
  $Line = $Line -replace '[#]+','#'

  $Line | Out-File $EmptyFile -Append -Encoding ascii

  $LineCount++
}
```

### More Information

- [Are there good references for moving from Perl to Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331873/are-there-good-references-for-moving-from-perl-to-powershell)
- [How to use operator '-replace' in PowerShell to replace strings of texts with special characters and replace successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794187/how-to-use-operator-replace-in-powershell-to-replace-strings-of-texts-with-sp)
- [about_Comparison_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847759.aspx)
- http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html

Comment: Frode. F's worked great, I attemted to run yours with no success. It did not error either... not sure why it didn't work

Comment: I can have another look; I'd at least like this to be a useful answer. :) I happened to be doing almost exactly this same thing in work today so it is fresh in my mind.

Comment: If it isn't working the most likely the `-match` part isn't working. The bit in quotes after `-match` is interpreted as a regex, so if **$web** contains special characters there could be a problem. In my own testing of the code above I set `$web = "localhost"` and, using a default hosts file, it prefixed the three lines with "localhost" in them with a "# ". I'll put some edits in the answer though...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to verify what was in there and then add entries, you could use the below which is designed to be ran interactively and returns any existing entries you specify in the varibles:

Note: the `t is powershell's in script method for 'Tab' command.

```
$hostscontent

# Script to Verify and Add Host File Entries

$hostfile = gc 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'
$hostscontent1 = $hostfile | select-string "autodiscover.XXX.co.uk"
$hostscontent2 = $hostfile | select-string "webmail.XXX.co.uk"
$1 = "XX.XX.XXX.XX`tautodiscover.XXX.co.uk"
$2 = "webmail.XXX.co.uk"




# Replace this machines path with a path to your list of machines e.g. $machines = gc \\machine\machines.txt
$machines = gc 'c:\mytestmachine.txt'
ForEach ($machine in $machines) {

                                If ($hostscontent1 -ne $null) { 
                                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                                Write-Host "$machine Already has Entry $1" -ForegroundColor Green

} Else { 
        Write-Host "Adding Entry $1 for $machine" -ForegroundColor Green
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        Add-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Value "XX.XX.XXX.XX`tautodiscover.XXX.co.uk" -Force

}

                                If ($hostscontent2 -ne $null) {
                                Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                                Write-Host "$machine Already has Entry $2" -ForegroundColor Green

} Else {
        Write-Host "Adding Entry $2 for $machine" -ForegroundColor Green
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        Add-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Value "XX.XX.XXX.XX`twebmail.XXX.co.uk" -Force

}
    }
```